# Problems sending json from postman

Tags: json, postman

I have a model with a `List<string> Parameters {get; set;}` property, so when I send from postman a json like this

```
{
    ...,
    "Parameters" :
    [
        ["FirstParam"],
        ["SecondParam"]
    ],
    ...
}
```

I receive `null` in my controller method, I mean the `requestModel` is `null`

```
public JsonResult GetBalances([FromBody]RequestModel requestModel)
{
    ...
}
```

I know that "Parameters" is the problem because when I send without it, I receive the model normally.

How can I receive a list of parameters(string) from a json format?

PD. It works when I create a model like

```
public class RequestModel
{
    ...
    public List<Parameters> Parameters {get;set;}
}

public class Parameters 
{ 
    public string Name {get;set;} 
}
```

And the json

```
{
    ...,
    "Parameters" : [
        {"Name": "FirstParameter"}, 
        {"Name":"SecondParameter"}
    ]
    ...
}
```

But I wonder if it is possible get it without create a class. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, the json format was wrong. My final json:

```
{
    ...,
    "Parameters" :
    [
        "FirstParam",
        "SecondParam"
    ],
    ...
}
```

I think I was sending a list of arrays of strings (or something like that). Now I can use `List<string>` as a property in my model.

Comment: Both json are valid, the thing is one is an array and the other one is a array of arrays I think

Comment: Run the JSON through http://json2csharp.com/ ...it will show you the json represented as classes.

Comment: Great tool!, I got `List<List<string>>`, that was my error. Thanks